Application compiled with pyinstaller does not run
I am working on a project with a graphical interface made with Python 3, but when creating an executable with PyInstaller, it generates the .exe file and compiled dependencies. However, upon trying to run the executable, a console window briefly opens and then closes without launching anything. The command used is: path_to_master_file.py -i path_to_icon --collect-submodules imports.
The modules I import include numpy, multiprocessing, tkinter, colorsys, math, primer3, Bio.SeqUtils, and additionally, I import several .py files which are custom libraries, meaning they are .py files in the same directory as the master file containing functions for organizational purposes (the project is quite large with over 1500 lines of code in total). The issue does not seem to be with tkinter; I've tested compiling a simple graphical interface which works. My first line of code in the master file after importing everything is multiprocessing.freeze_support().
The only message that appears in the terminal both when launching with the executable and using cmd is: longjump, immediately after which the window closes when using the native executable. When I use -d imports instead of --collect-submodules imports, I can see that the dependencies are imported, but ultimately, it still encounters the longjump error.
Needless to say, the code runs perfectly fine from the Python interpreter.
As additional information, my computer has an AMD Ryzen 5 processor, an NVIDIA GTX 1650 graphics card, the C: drive is a 160 GB SSD, the D: drive is a 1 TB HDD, and it has 12 GB of DDR5 RAM.
So far, I have tried the --onefile option, testing to see if tkinter or multiprocessing were the issue, running as administrator, and attempting to compile from an administrator terminal. Up to now, I have not been able to replicate the issue or compile a functional executable of the project, so I have no idea what is causing it or how to fix it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

actualización, probando todas la cosas que se me ocurrieron sin ninguna idea de que causaba el problema pude rastrear el error a el modulo primer3, el código necesario para replicar el problema es import primer3 as p print(p..calc_tm("AAACTACA") y compilar con pyinstalle
